# There are 5 persons live in a room.every one of them has 3 clothes.in how many ways they can wear 3 clothes in case that those are not for them

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

There are 5 persons live in a room.every one of them has a coat,a shirt and a pair of shoes.in how many ways they can wear coat, shirt and shoes in case that those are not for them.
(I mean no one should were his own clothes.)
(we don't have Slip-on shoes every one put on a pair of shoes)

Comment: Consider derrangement $D5^3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, we need to consider derrangement of five objects.

Suppose we have a set of 5 person as P1 P2 P3 P4 P5

then we have their respective coats  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5

No one wear their own coat so derrangement $D_5=44$

Now repeat it for shirts and shoes and we have requisite derrangement $D_5^3=44^3$